# Program crashing and returning code 255

Tags: c, runtime-error

```
#include <stdio.h>
int findnumb(int max)
{
    static int total=2;
    static int desk=1;
    if(total>max)   
    {
    return 0;
    }
    else
    {   
        if(desk>=total)
        {
        total++;
        desk=1;
        return findnumb(max);
        }
        else
        {
        desk++;
        int left=desk*(desk-1)/2;
        int right=(total*(total+1)/2)-(desk*(desk+1)/2);
            if(left==right) 
            {
            printf("Desk number %d, number of participants %d\n", desk, total);
            return findnumb(max);
            }
        return findnumb(max);
        }
    }
}



main()
{
    int max;
    printf("Enter the upper bound:\n");
    scanf(" %d", &max);
    printf("------------------------\n");
    findnumb(max);
    printf("Search is complete");

}
```

It is for a riddle like this:

Suppose that there exists a meeting and we do not know how many people attend to it. However, we see a man quitting from the meeting. If we ask the man how many people exist at the meeting he just replies “I do not know”. Nonetheless he says “I was sitting on a chair numbered x and summation of the numbers below and above me equals. In other words, if the number of the chair is x, then 1,2,3….x-1 = x+1 x+2 …...t-1,t (total participant count). Besides, we do not know the value of t and the chair number x. Total participant 8, and the chair number 6 is an example configuration. Because 1+2+3+4+5 = 7+8 = 15. Your task is to find similar configurations by one by one try-out.

And It wants the solution to implement a recursive function.

So when I run this code it can't manage a scanf'ed value bigger than 360 while crashing and terminating with return code 255, so how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe it is a stack overflow ...

Comment: Sure is a stack overflow the number of recursive calls are O(n^2) -> for 360 -> since 360^2 = 129600 recursive call on the stack :)

Comment: Congratulations, you've found the main purpose of recursion outside algorithm theory: burning all available RAM and creating stack overflows. As a bonus your program also runs much slower than it otherwise could, and is far less readable.

Comment: It's as pointless to do this recusively. An iterative approach for this problem is far more efficient and you won't get any stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't want to get into a war, but I voted this up after someone voted it down. The poster is obviously a novice but that's not a vote down offence and has clearly done some research including identifying the critical value (360) that blows the code and told us the return value.
It would be a shame if you can't find out about stack overflow by posting to Stackoverflow.com!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've said nothing about your platform and exit-codes are typically platform dependent.

However a possible cause is (ironically) a stack overflow!
Not only is that the name of this site but it's a real thing.

All systems have a practical limit on recursion and to be honest 360 is a shed load of recursion.

You might be able to modify the size of the stack in a compiler directive or option.
If not you might have to 'unravel' the recursive code into a sequential program.

It's often the case that you can allocate more space off the heap than the system will accept in recursive calls.